# Error : Exporting excel through XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, export-to-excel

i'm exporting excel file through `xml` and `xslt` and getting this error..when trying to open this file...this is the log file

```
XML ERROR in Table
REASON: Bad Value
FILE:   C:\Documents and Settings\mayankp\Desktop\PrintCheckList.xls
GROUP:  Row
TAG:    Cell
ATTRIB: Index
VALUE:  0

XML ERROR in Table
REASON: Bad Value
FILE:   C:\Documents and Settings\mayankp\Desktop\PrintCheckList.xls
GROUP:  Row
TAG:    Cell
ATTRIB: Index
VALUE:  1

XML ERROR in Table
REASON: Bad Value
FILE:   C:\Documents and Settings\mayankp\Desktop\PrintCheckList.xls
GROUP:  Row
TAG:    Cell
ATTRIB: Index
VALUE:  2

XML ERROR in Table
REASON: Bad Value
FILE:   C:\Documents and Settings\mayankp\Desktop\PrintCheckList.xls
GROUP:  Row
TAG:    Cell
ATTRIB: Index
VALUE:  0

XML ERROR in Table
REASON: Bad Value
FILE:   C:\Documents and Settings\mayankp\Desktop\PrintCheckList.xls
GROUP:  Row
TAG:    Cell
ATTRIB: Index
VALUE:  1

XML ERROR in Table
REASON: Bad Value
FILE:   C:\Documents and Settings\mayankp\Desktop\PrintCheckList.xls
GROUP:  Row
TAG:    Cell
ATTRIB: Index
VALUE:  2
```

any help is appreciated.

**Edit** : see complete XML [here](http://pastebin.mozilla.org/1770372)

Comment: We really need to see the contents of you xls file (I am assuming it is an Excel XML file) to be able to help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The XML sample isn't complete, but looking at it, the issues may lie with your second row

```
     <Row ss:Height="15.75" ss:StyleID="s62">
        <Cell ss:MergeDown="2" ss:StyleID="m57097196">
           <Data ss:Type="String">S/N</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:MergeDown="2" ss:StyleID="m57097216">
           <Data ss:Type="String">PRIORITY</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:MergeDown="2" ss:StyleID="m57097076">
           <Data ss:Type="String">ITEM </Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:MergeAcross="2" ss:StyleID="m57097176">
           <Data ss:Type="String">AUDIT TYPE </Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:MergeDown="2" ss:StyleID="m57097236">
           <Data ss:Type="String">STATUS </Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:MergeDown="2" ss:StyleID="m57097280">
           <Data ss:Type="String">REFERENCE </Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:MergeDown="2" ss:StyleID="m57097056">
           <Data ss:Type="String">AUDIT REMARKS</Data>
        </Cell>
     </Row>
```

In particular the **ss:MergeDown** and **ss:MergeAcross** attributes. If you look at the [Microsoft Xml Spreadsheet Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140066%28v=office.10%29.aspx) you will see for **ss:MergeAcross** it says the following:

> Specifies the number of adjacent cells across (right unless in
>   right-to-left mode) from the current cell to merge.  As mentioned
>   above, indices must not overlap. If duplicates exist, the behavior is
>   unspecified and the XML Spreadsheet document is considered invalid.

So, you may be getting the error because the following Cell is positioned in column 5, and this overlaps Cell in column 4, which spreads across the following two cells. You need to explicitly set the index of the fifth cell to be in column 7. (Note the use of ss:Index="7" in the fifth cell).

```
     <Row ss:Height="15.75" ss:StyleID="s62">
        <Cell ss:MergeDown="2" ss:StyleID="m57097196">
           <Data ss:Type="String">S/N</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:MergeDown="2" ss:StyleID="m57097216">
           <Data ss:Type="String">PRIORITY</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:MergeDown="2" ss:StyleID="m57097076">
           <Data ss:Type="String">ITEM </Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:MergeAcross="2" ss:StyleID="m57097176">
           <Data ss:Type="String">AUDIT TYPE </Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:Index="7" ss:MergeDown="2" ss:StyleID="m57097236">
           <Data ss:Type="String">STATUS </Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:MergeDown="2" ss:StyleID="m57097280">
           <Data ss:Type="String">REFERENCE </Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:MergeDown="2" ss:StyleID="m57097056">
           <Data ss:Type="String">AUDIT REMARKS</Data>
        </Cell>
     </Row>
```

Additionallly, because of the use of **ss:Mergedown**, set to 2 for the cells, this means the next two rows are taken up. Therefore the next Row element in your xml should be changed to explicitly set the index to 5 so as not to overlap.

```
     <Row ss:Index="5" ss:Height="30">
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s76">
           <Data ss:Type="String">1</Data>
        </Cell>
```

This should hopefully fix your problems.